# Paypal REST API v1 localize error message

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

We are using PayPal express checkout REST API v1 server-to-server
In case of PayPal API endpoint exception, it's possible to get localized error message?

Answer (score 0):

The exceptions/error messages remains same globally,hence not possible to get localized exceptions/error messages from PayPal.